# How to use command \LaTeX{} in .bib like in .tex?

Tags: bibtex

My .bib file contains this:

```
@article{shell2002use,  
    title={How to Use the IEEEtran LaTeX Class},  
    author={Shell, Michael},  
    journal={Journal of LATEX Class Files},  
    volume={1},  
    number={11},  
    pages={10--20},  
    year={2002}  
}
```

and I get this:

```
[1] M. Shell, “How to use the ieeetran class,” Journal of LATEX Class Files, vol. 1, no. 11, pp. 10–20, 2002.
```

How to get the effect like use `\LaTeX{}` in `.tex` file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many BibTeX bibliography style files employ *sentence style* to render the contents of the `title` field of entries of type `@article`, `@techreport`, and `@misc`, i.e., they turn uppercase letters (except the very first letter) into lowercase letters. You can prevent this by enclosing the words in question (and even the entire title field) inside an extra pair of braces. In your case enclosing `\LaTeX{}` or the entire title (better) inside a pair of braces like:

```
title={{How to Use the IEEEtran \LaTeX{} Class}},
```

makes capital letters and IEEEtran retain their attributes additionally.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
  @article{shell2002use,
    title={{How to Use the IEEEtran \LaTeX{} Class}},
    author={Shell, Michael},
    journal={Journal of \LaTeX{} Class Files},
    volume={1},
    number={11},
    pages={10--20},
    year={2002}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
  \cite{shell2002use}
  \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
  \bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: BibTeX doesn't have this happit. It's simple related to the bibliography style which uses the bibtex command `change.case$` for titles. So Please clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel May be. But whatever style/s I use do this. I agree with you that this is due to `change.case$`. I edited. Hope it is enough. Thanks for noting.

Comment: I've take the liberty of rephrasing the first sentence of your answer to highlight that "sentence style", if in use, applies mainly to the `title` fields of certain entry types.

Comment: @Mico: The power of a native speaker ;-)

Comment: It would be good if capital letters in math mode survives.